# Display Notification When New Page Load in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension in google chrome.I want to show desktop notification when any new page loads in currently active tab.

But my written code is not working properly.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {    
      chrome.notifications.create(‘id1’, {   
         type: ‘basic’,
         iconUrl: ‘icon.png’,
         title: ‘Review Baed Surfing’,
         message: ‘Check URL now by clicking FAKE URL icon infront on Address Bar!’,
         priority: 0
       },
       function() { /* Error checking goes here */}
     );        
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console ? Please check console on background page.

Comment: those are not the correct quote characters. Not sure if this a copy paste error though. `type: ‘basic’` should be `type: "basic"`

Comment: console shows error near "chrome.notifications.create("
error is,
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: @TrojanHorse Please write your quotes properly. Use " "

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to call chrome.notifications.create() in background script and chrome.tabs.executeScript only accept file url or code (css, js) to inject.

And you could check the following items when the notification doesn't show as expected:

1. Add "notification" to permissions in manifest.json.

   ```
   "permissions": ["notifications"]
   ```
2. Notifications API only supports Windows, Chrome OS and Mac currently.
3. The 'option' parameter of create function must include a notification title, message and iconUrl. The rich notification will not work properly without any error if you missed any one of them.

   ```
   var opt = {
       type: "basic",
       title: "Primary Title",
       message: "Primary message to display",
       iconUrl: "url_to_small_icon"
   }
   ```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

i make following changes in code

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
 if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
    chrome.notifications.create('id1',{   
     type: 'basic',
     iconUrl: 'icon.png',
     title: 'Review Baed Surfing',
     message: 'Check URL now by clicking FAKE URL icon infront on Address Bar!',
     priority: 0
   },
   function() { /* Error checking goes here */}
   ); 
  }
});
```

Now it works properly.

Thank You,